How can I repair my Reolink PoE camera after water damage on the ethernet connection?
I have a Reolink RLC-520 security camera. It is for external use and has PoE (power over Ethernet, so a simple network cable also gives power to the camera). The waterproof cap that comes with the camera is either not good or very tricky to install.
As my camera was installed outdoors, water got into the network connector and the camera stopped working. This is the state of the connection pins. How can I fix this?


This is very easy to fix if you know how to create an Ethernet cable, and believe me that this is a very easy process, just check any of the many tutorials online (e.g. this, this...).
Since the pins of the connector are damaged, it is necessary to replace it. You may try to clean them but most likely this will not work if water made the same damage as shown in the picture. To replace the original Reolink connector, either you:

Use a keystone jack and dolphin clips (so it remains a Female connection) or…
You crimp your own RJ45 connector to have a male connector - for this you will also need an additional RJ45 Female-Female connector.

I will describe the second solution. For this, you will need:

An Ethernet cable crimper.
An RJ45 cap.
An RJ45 F/F connector.

STEPS:

Cut off the old damaged connector and open the outer cable to get to reach the coloured wires inside. Be careful not to cut the coloured wires when opening the external cable.


Prepare and straighten the cables.


Insert the cables in the Ethernet cap. I am using Pass-Through, which is quite nice, so the cables will go through the Ethernet cap (see image). My crimper can cut automatically the excess of cable during the crimping process. Note that the cables have to be in a specific position (not standard 568B). From the side you enter the cables this is: orange/white, orange, green/white, grey, X, green, purple, X (note that the image below show them in reverse because this is the other side). The Reolink camera only has 6 cables, not 8. So these "X" are in theory empty. However, for a proper crimping, use a couple of dummy cut cables (you can get them from any Ethernet cable, just cut a few cms).

You can see better in this image that the couple of cables in the "X" positions do not lead to anywhere:


Now it is time to insert the cable in the crimper (on the 8P) and press hard.

The cable is created:


Finally, use an RJ45 female-female connector similar to this:

And connect the camera on one end and the network cable on the other:



The camera should work with no problems, including PoE.
